# Meson: ERROR: add_project_arguments keyword argument "language" unknown languages: python

Tags: meson-build

I want to install [this](https://github.com/infirit/caja-admin) project with meson. It worked flawlessly all the time but since about three weeks it fails with (I think because of the latest 0.59 release, could not find any changes that could have caused this):

```sh
po/meson.build:3:0: ERROR: add_project_arguments keyword argument "language" unknown languages: python
```

This is the content of the meson.build in the po directory:

```py
i18n = import('i18n')
# define GETTEXT_PACKAGE
add_project_arguments('-DGETTEXT_PACKAGE="caja-admin"', language:'python')
i18n.gettext(meson.project_name(),
    args: '--directory=' + meson.source_root()
)
```

Comment: Try replacing `python` with `cython`

Comment: Great thanks, this works! But do you know why python is not supported or what the problem was?

Comment: That's my fault :) Meson used to not validate the language arguments, and if you passed an invalid one Meson would silently ignore it, I changed Meson to actually check that the language is supported, and otherwise error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meson provides native support for building Cython programs or extensions. Building Python programs is the job of a Python interpreter (like Cython).

See [this](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-tables.html#language-arguments-parameter-names) for the list of possible values that can be passed to the `language` parameter.